# How to build a map from two lists using zip?

Tags: python-2.7

here is my list:

`projects = ["A", "B", "C"]`

`hours = [1,2,3]`

I want my final answer to be like: `{A:1,B:2,C:3}`

Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to call dict constructor?

```
dict(zip(projects,hours))
```

The code fragment `zip(projects,hours)` will generate a list of tuples `(key,value)` which will be used to feed the map (usually called dictionary in python) constructor: `dict`

Comment: My answer is {'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2}, but I want it to be exactly {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}. I used "sorted", but it only printed out "A, B, C", which missed the value of dictionary

Comment: @user3430643 Dictionaries are not ordered by insertion order but by the hash code of their keys, that is the reason why printing shows `{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2}`

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.7 is also "dictionary comprehension"

```
>>> projects = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> hours = [1,2,3]
>>> res = {project: hours for project, hours in zip(projects, hours)}
>>> res
... {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is {'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2}, but I want it to be exactly {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}. I used "sorted", but it only printed out "A, B, C", which missed the value of dictionary